# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, maven-3

I have encountered problems while trying to run sonarqube on my application. When I execute the command it throws me an error which doesn't say much to me. Does anyone know where is the problem here?

The Error looks like this:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.257 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-07T15:10:39+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project TeamTracker: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.sca
nner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.la
ng.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.1.2184.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.2.588/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.2.588.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/A113408609/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security
.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @26f204a4
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is a command I execute:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN -Dsonar.projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY -Dsonar.projectName=$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG
```

I have gone through documentations but I still really can't see what is the problem here :/

When I try to run `mvn clean install` the build is succesfull.

I am using Java 11, Maven 3.6.3 and Sonar Community Edition Version 8.9.10

Comment: Use Maven 3.8.6 instead of that old version of Maven...